# Add Close Accordion Function to Jquery Script

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a script found here:

```
(function() {

    var $container = $('.acc-container'),
        $trigger   = $('.acc-trigger');

    $container.hide();
    $trigger.first().addClass('active').next().show();

    var fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true);
    $trigger.css('width', fullWidth);
    $container.css('width', fullWidth);

    $trigger.on('click', function(e) {
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $trigger.removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(300);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Resize
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        fullWidth = $container.outerWidth(true)
        $trigger.css('width', $trigger.parent().width() );
        $container.css('width', $container.parent().width() );
    });

})();
```

And I can't figure out where to add the ability to not automatically reveal the first tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$('.acc-container').accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
});
```